nginx "set_verify_client" does not accept mapped variables
This is a very reduced configuration for nginx, which should use different configurations for TLS connections, based on SNI names.
Some of them need additional client authentication via client certificates.
When I try to configure it, nging -t claims, that the mapped variable is not valid for ssl_verify_client: invalid value "$svc" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:24
The configuration looks like:
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    default           server_one;
    two.example.org   server_two;
  }  
  
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $authen_cert {
    default           "/etc/nginx/public.cert";
    two.example.org   "None";
  }  
  
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $svc {
    default           "on";
    two.example.org   "off";
  }

  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:3128 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$name/privkey.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate $authen_cert ;
    #set $svc ="off";
    ssl_verify_client $svc ;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.2:3128;
  }    
}

I tried different names for the variable, guessing that I had an conflict with some predefined stuff, but no matter, how I name this variable, or if I set it explicitly before the statement, the error message is the same.
The position of the map block makes also no difference.
I can map the arguments for all other statements to variables without any problem.
I tried finally also an if-block for both verification related lines, but this also gives an error:"if" directive is not allowed here
So I am clueless, how I shall configure this.
nginx is: nginx version: nginx/1.22.1
system is: SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1
Thanks for any hints
Thanks to Lana Codes I could overcome the first error, with ssl_verify_client. But after that was fixed, I got the same error message for ssl_client_certificate . I fixed this with setting a fixed path to a file, containing several client certificates, as verification is now optional.
OK, now the configuration test was ok, but I learned, that the mapping itself is not working. If I omit the default, I get no connection at all.
All, what I want to create, is a simple TLS-Termination service, which passes the unencrypted stream to an unencrypted plain tcp application.
I tried with different variations in the configuration:

the keyword ssl behind the listen statement
like in the above example:  I see no SNI name recognition in the logs, but an empty map and finally no certificate found, as the variable is unset
without the keyword ssl behind the listen statement
Now I see a SNI recognition, but no map and no signs, that nginx tries to terminate TLS, the connection fails.
I tried to have ssl_pre_read on in the server or the stream block, I tried it in both blocks, all the time the configuration is valid, but not working as expected.


OK, every works, when I just replace $ssl_preread_server_name with $ssl_server_name
Thanks again for the help!

Much simpler. Lol.

Yeah if is not allowed in stream, got to use maps. Try setting ssl_verify_client optional; and the sniffing the $ssl_client_verify variable for a NONE value. This should work or at least get you close.
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    default           server_one;
    two.example.org   server_two;
  }  
  
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $authen_cert {
    default           "/etc/nginx/public.cert";
    two.example.org   "None";
  }  
  map $ssl_client_verify $no_client_cert_sent {
    default           0;
    NONE              1;
  }
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $allow_no_client_cert_server_name {
    default           0;
    two.example.org   1;
  }
  map $no_client_cert_sent$allow_no_client_cert_server_name $proxy {
    default 127.0.0.2:3128; # default proxy along
    # if $ssl_client_verify = NONE && $ssl_preread_server_name NOT IN allow list
    # then proxy to server that only returns 496 cert required
    10      127.0.0.1:8888; 
  }

  # dead end proxy for clients that sent no cert without being in the allow map
  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8888;
    return 469;
  }

  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:3128 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$name/privkey.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate $authen_cert ;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
    proxy_pass $proxy;
  }    
}


Thanks for your valuable answer, showing another trick, to overcome configuration shortcomings. But unfortunately the problem is bigger, than I thought. I try to extend my question, as this comments restricts length of my text
